# A* Optimality with consistent heuristic

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Where can I find a proof for the following theorem:

Theorem: If h(n) is consistent, A* using GRAPH-SEARCH is optimal

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a question for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 5):

You can find it in this book on page 95-97:

[http://www.amazon.com/Artificial-Intelligence-Modern-Approach-3rd/dp/0136042597/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1295781411&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136042597)

The basic outline of the proof is:

First we define these functions:

g(n) = cost to reach node from start node

f(n) = g(n) + h(n)

Steps:

1. Establish that the values of f(n) along any path are nondecreasing, if h(n) is consistent.
2. Prove that whenever A* selects a node for expansion, the optimal path to that node has been found.

Step 1 follows directly from the definition of consistency.

Step 2 is proved by seeing, that if it wasn't true, there would have to be another frontier node n' on the optimal path from the start node to n, but this cannot be, as paths are nondecreasing and hence that node would have lower f cost than than n. I.e. f(n) = g(n) + h(n) > f(n') = g(n') + h(n')

Answer (score 0):

read [this page](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~anderson/cs440/index.html/doku.php?id=notes:week4c)

Two Steps for proof:

```
1- Establish that the values of f(n) along any path are nondecreasing, if h(n) is consistent.

2- Prove that whenever A* selects a node for expansion, the optimal path to that node has been found.
```